# How was GPS not freely available for civilian use before 1983

Tags: gps

In 1983 GPS was made freely available for civilian use, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System:

> President Ronald Reagan issued a directive making GPS freely available
>   for civilian use, once it was sufficiently developed, as a common
>   good.

**How (technically) it was not freely available for civilian use before 1983?**

Was the signal not on public radio frequency, obfuscated, coded, ciphered? Maybe the HW (e.g. chips) was not available to civilian electronics devices manufacturers?

Comment: This is more of a military technology export law question than a GIS one. If you think about the computer technology of the time (the "Turbo" button hadn't yet been invented) and the cost of the early surveying units, even making it "available" didn't make it *accessible*.

Comment: Does anybody remember Selective Availability?  Even after Reagan made GPS available, its accuracy was systematically degraded (until Clinton changed that over a decade later).

Comment: It's (and maybe was?) encoded with CDMA, its signal is probably below noise level in most places, and you receive the signal of several satellites at the same time on the same frequency, so if you don't know the CDMA sequence of each satellite, it'll probably be impossible to hear, let alone make sense, the signals.

Comment: @whuber I think the accuracy today is still not as good as it could be, the more precise version being encrypted and only for military use? Maybe before Clinton the public version was even less accurate on purpose?

Comment: @user276648 That is precisely what "Selective Availability" was: purposeful degradation of the signal.  Civilian applications (using short times without differential correction) typically experienced 30 - 50 m accuracy, about ten times worse than today.  I don't want to debate any speculative theories about what's going on today, but it's worth pointing out that scientists are using GPS for sub-centimeter level positioning.  That shows how over sufficiently long periods of time today's GPS is extremely accurate.

Comment: meanwhile I found interesting video on that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozAPGnr-934